# How to extract the text file from zip into zip using Python

Tags: python, file, zip

i have to extract text file from the zip into zip

i have structure like this

```
abc.zip
|
|_n.zip_
|       |_Final.text
|     
|_abc.pdf
|_rc_.pdf
```

i need final.txt file from abc.zip/n.zip/Final.txt

i try with

```
import zipfile
path = "/abc.zip/
with zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the files step by step

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('abc.zip') as file:
    file.extract('n.zip')

with ZipFile('n.zip') as file:
    file.extract('final.txt')
```

Finally, if you want a clean directory, use `os.remove('file_name')` to delete the file you want